# Check which rows a formula refers to in Excel (error checking with VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to use VBA to list all the rows a formula refers to?

I have built a spreadsheet that should only refer to cells in the same row, and any formulas referring to a different row are in error. I cannot work out how to do this in VBA. As an example, the third formula would be in error.

```
=(D3+F3)/(E3+D3)
=D4/E4
=D5^E5+F12
=D6+F6^G6
```

Comment: And what you expect from us? Do you think that someone will write a code for you?

Comment: You could have a macro go through all cells, grab any formulas (if a cell is a formula, get the formula), then put that info into maybe a CSV where each line is a formula. Then just scan against that line?  There's a bunch of ways I can think to do this. What have you tried so far? What does or doesn't work?

Comment: You could probably use the `.FormulaR1C1` property of each cell and look to see if there is an occurrence of `"R["` within it.

Comment: https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2014/01/14/vba-determine-all-precedent-cells-a-nice-example-of-recursion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i can understand the reason you want to check if formula refer for single row only...

Here's what i wrote. Please, read comments in code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckFormulas()
Dim c As Range
Dim wsh As Worksheet
Dim sformula As String

'context
Set wsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
'loop through the set of cells in UsedRange
For Each c In wsh.UsedRange
    'formula starts with "="
    If c.Formula Like "=*" Then
        sformula = c.Formula
        'check if formula refer to single row
        'if not, change background color form this cell
        If DoesFormulaReferToSingleRow(sformula) Then
            c.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub

'needs reference to MS VBScript Regular Expression 5.5
'           MS Scripting RunTime
Function DoesFormulaReferToSingleRow(sFormulaToCheck As String) As Boolean
Dim bRetVal As Boolean, sPattern As String
Dim re As VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp, mc As VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection, m As VBScript_RegExp_55.Match
Dim oDict As Scripting.Dictionary

bRetVal = False

sPattern = "\d{1,}"

Set re = New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
With re
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = False
    .Pattern = sPattern
    Set mc = .Execute(sFormulaToCheck)
End With

Set oDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

For Each m In mc
    If Not oDict.Exists(m.Value) Then
        oDict.Add m.Value, m.Length
    End If
Next

bRetVal = Not (oDict.Count = 1)

Exit_DoesFormulaReferToSingleRow
    On Error Resume Next
    Set m = Nothing
    Set mc = Nothing
    Set re = Nothing
    Set oDict = Nothing
    DoesFormulaReferToSingleRow = bRetVal
    Exit Function

Err_DoesFormulaReferToSingleRow:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, Err.Number
    Resume Exit_DoesFormulaReferToSingleRow
End Function
```

As you can see, i used [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yab2dx62(v=vs.84).aspx) and [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4(v=vs.84).aspx) object. Do not formget to add references.

For further details, about above objects, please see:
[Regex - syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1400241x(v=vs.84).aspx)
[Creating a Regular Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee236359(v=vs.84).aspx)
[Microsoft Beefs Up VBScript with Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx)

Comment: This works really well! I tried to change the Regex to only find actual cell references (e.g. of the form AB11 only). Currently the VBA above is finding instances of AB10+1000, where only AB10 should be picked up, not the +1000. I tried using the Regex `(?:[A-Z]).(\d{1,})`, but that doesn't seem to work in the VBA script. It does work in https://www.debuggex.com/ though.

Comment: Very minor... but there should be a `:` after `Exit_DoesFormulaReferToSingleRow`

Comment: @GlobalSprawl +1 for `:`. What you mean by "Very minor...". Have you an idea how to achieve that? Or have you any suggestion to my code?

Comment: I meant by "very minor" that it was a small thing that I spotted compared to what you have done with this code. My only question was how to use Regex to isolate numbers that refer to a row (i.e. follow letters in Excel format e.g. AB10, and not the number in divide by 1000 for example). I am really grateful for your help with this that I simply could not have done myself.

Comment: @GlobalSprawl. Thank you very much for explanation. Note, taht English is not my native language and sometimes i need few words more to be sure that i understand it correctly.

Comment: As to the code... as far as i remember you wanted to check if formula refers to the same row. So, the code is checking if there is one or more numbers that refer to the Excel row.

Comment: If a formula looks like `=(D3+F3)/(E3+D3)/1000` it treats it as an error because `3≠1000`. But the formula is correct. I tried to change the Regex to only find numbers that came after a letter (i.e. Excel cell references format) using the Regex `(?:[A-Z]).(\d{1,})`. I tested it in https://www.debuggex.com/ and it worked. But it didn't work in the VBA script. That was my suggestion. Thank you again.

Comment: Ok, i understand your doubt now. Change pattern to: `[A-Za-z]{1,}.\d(1,)`. This should work as well. Cheers, Maciej

Comment: The pattern you suggest returns both the letters and numbers (i.e. AB10 not just the 10). It needs a lookbehind like `(?<[A-Z]).(\d{1,})` but this is not available in VBA. I tried using `SubMatches` with the `Execute` method, but it is giving a compile error. Have spent ages on this. Would really appreciate a bit more help. To be clear, it highlights in red when the formula includes another number (e.g. `=(D3+F3)/(E3+D3)/1000` shows as an error when it is correct).

Comment: I'll check that tomorrow. Now, it's bit late.